# Sequential file name problem (Python/Picam)

Tags: python, raspicam, pi-zero

I would be very grateful for some guidance on the following script. You will see that I have very little experience (3 days!).

Using the pantilthat servo control, I am taking a image (jpg) at various camera positions. This is in a continuous loop that will be run during daylight hours.

I am trying to save the images like so, 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg..... 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg.... etc etc

The code works, but I just cant figure out the file naming part.
Thank you for looking and any improvents gratefully received.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pantilthat
import time
import picamera
x = 0
while x < 9:
        print "Take Photo"
        with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
                camera.resolution = (1024, 768)
                camera.start_preview()
                camera.annotate_text = 'Picture Taken with Raspberry camera'
                time.sleep(2)
                for filename in camera.record_sequence(
                'image%02d.jpg' % i for i in range(1)):
                        print('Saving to %s' % filename)
                camera.stop_preview()
                print('Done')
        x += 1
        if x == 1:
                print("1")
                pantilthat.pan(30)
                pantilthat.tilt(-10)
                time.sleep(1)
        elif x == 2:
                print("2")
                pantilthat.pan(20)
                pantilthat.tilt(0)
                time.sleep(1)
         elif x == 3:
                pantilthat.pan(10)
                pantilthat.tilt(10)
                print("3")
                time.sleep(1)
        elif x == 4:
                pantilthat.pan(0)
                pantilthat.tilt(-10)
                print("4")
                time.sleep(1)
        elif x == 5:
                pantilthat.pan(-10)
                pantilthat.tilt(10)
                print("5")
                time.sleep(1)
        elif x == 6:
                pantilthat.pan(-20)
                pantilthat.tilt(-20)
                print("6")
                time.sleep(1)
       elif x == 7:
                pantilthat.pan(-30)
                pantilthat.tilt(20)
                print("7")
                time.sleep(1)
                x=0
        else:
                pass
```

Comment: According to the docs record_sequence records a sequence of video clips! https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.10/api_camera.html#picamera.camera.PiCamera.record_sequence Don't you just want to capture one image each time the camera moves?

Comment: you explained what  filenames you want ..... you did not explain what filenames you get when you run the program

Comment: looks like your camera gets positioned after you take a picture .... is that how you want the program to behave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like the following.

I'm using a list to store your pan and tilt values and capturing 1 image on each loop. Simply concatenating the string value of i onto 'image' followed by .'jpg' to create the image name.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pantilthat,time,picamera

panTilt = [[ 30, -10],
           [ 20,   0],
           [ 10,  10],
           [  0, -10],
           [-10,  10],
           [-20, -20],
           [-30,  20],
           [  0,   0]]

camera=picamera.PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (1024, 768)
camera.annotate_text = 'Picture Taken with Raspberry camera'

for i,(pan,tilt) in enumerate(panTilt):
    print("Take Photo")
    camera.capture('image'+str(i)+'.jpg')
    print(i,pan,tilt)
    pantilthat.pan(pan)
    pantilthat.tilt(tilt)
    time.sleep(1)

camera.close()
```

Comment: That is a good way to significantly simplify the OP's code. To make it (imho) slightly more pythonic you could turn that while loop to: `for i, (pan, tilt) in enumerate(panTilt):` and use the `i` for counting up the filename and `pan` and `tilt` instead of `panTilt[x][0]`. 

    `

Comment: @CoderMike What a neat method you have provided with the table. I don't know why, but when I run your code, I get an error after image 6. I inserted a sleep period (60 secs) thinking it might be the camera not keeping up with instructions, but the error persisted. Do I need to keep the interpreter 'alive' ? 

This is the error message ;

Comment: Exception in thread Thread-13 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 1071, in run  
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 614, in wait
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 364, in wait
     <type 'exceptions.ValueError'>: list.remove(x): x not in list

Comment: I also noticed that the picam was 'on' permantly when I ran the code (as seen by the constant red LED). Would it not best to turn the camera off between images so as not to 'wear it out'?

@Ghanima. Thanks for your suggestions to make it more 'pythonic', but I am struggling to make it work at all !

(Incidentally, the camera will be used to monitor an airfield)  
   
thanks again

Comment: `'image%s.jpg'%i` :P

Comment: btw @CoderMike should you not be capturing _after_ panning and tilting? otherwise first image is probably at 0 pan, 0 tilt, and there is no image for the last pan and tilt (-30, 20)

Comment: @Rixster why do you seem to be using Python2.7? I would suggest Python3.

Comment: @Rixster are you running the code within some IDE eg IDLE or Thonny? What happens if you run from a terminal window 'python3 test.py'?

Comment: Update: SOLVED : I updated the shebang line to #!/usr/bin/env python3
and there were no more errors. Could you suggest a way to repeat the loop so that it continues indefinitly?

Comment: Just add 'while True:' before the for loop and indent. By the way, there is no harm leaving the camera on.

Comment: Pefect: Thank you very much for your help, esp @CoderMike